# Not able to connect to database in ASP IIS

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, database, visual-studio-2008

I was able to deloy my asp project on IIS and it shows the front page, there I have a login page , after entering the credentials it does not logs in, I used try and catch , and in catch it gave me an error, stating thread has aborted, it was on

> page.redirect["master.apsx",true]

so I changed it to

> page.redirect["master.aspx",false]

and it didnt gave error, but it was not able to login further, I guess it is not able to connect to database. So any help would be appreciable.

Thanks

CODE:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

strconn = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=" +    Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Securityservice.mdf") + ";Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";
    Label1.Text = "  conn string";

}
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
protected void btn_popup_quick_login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    try
    {
       if (txt_username.Text != null)
        {
            if (txt_password.Text != null)
            {

                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                conn = new SqlConnection(strconn);

                conn.Open();

                cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * From UserMaster Where Username=@username and Password=@password", conn);

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", txt_username.Text);

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", txt_password.Text);

                da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

                da.Fill(dt); 
                {
                    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                    {
                        userloginname = txt_username.Text;

                        userloginpassword = txt_password.Text;

                        Session["username"] = txt_username.Text;

                        MessageBox.Show("User Login Sucessfully", "Login", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk);

                        Response.Redirect("Marketing.aspx",false);

                    }

                    else
                    {
                        Label1.Text = "else part";
                        MessageBox.Show("Invalid User Name and Password", "Login", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk);
                        txt_username.Focus();

                    }
                    txt_username.Text = "";
                    txt_password.Text = "";
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.Message,"Error",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Error); }
    conn.Close();
    Label1.Text = "login";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check the connection strings in web.config, to make sure they still point to the proper location of the database after you deployed the site.

Comment: I have not used connection string in web.config, rather I have made connection on each page load

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem could be the `Application_Start` method.
Look if you have written some thing there.
Make a break point there and see is there any error.

Or have you written `Response.End()` in you code? 

 You need to provide more detail

1. You need to check weather you are able to connect to database or not.
2. You also need to check weather the page is called or not (which comes after login).

Comment: when I run from visual studio it works fine without any problem. But when I run it on IIS its not going further. I have not used

>Application_Start

neither

>Response.End()

Comment: are you able to connect to your database?

Comment: in visual studio?? yes
and my deployed as well as code is on same machine so I guess it is connecting to database

Comment: so you are not sure weather it is connecting to database or not. can you provide me the login code? I will alter the code to check weather it is connecting or not?

Comment: protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
strconn = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=" + Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Securityservice.mdf") + ";Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";
        Label1.Text = "  conn string";
      
    }

Comment: are you using asp.net or window application. **MessageBox.Show**?

Comment: then how are you using **MessageBox.Show**

Comment: so I shouldnt use it ??
I am new at asp.net I have used it on window form, so I thought to use it . Is it wrong ?

Comment: I have used AJAX on the page does it hinders in any way ??